# Flutter Future async function overwriting

Tags: flutter

Hi this function takes 2 parameter

```
  Future<void> _startDownload(String savePath, String pdfname) async {}

//And calling with
final savePath = path.join(dir.path, param + _fileName);
      await _startDownload(savePath, param);
```

It works fine once but when I call it again with same or differen pdfname parameter , it adds it to the end of url.

[The url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oG9a.png)

This is my code

```
String _fileUrl = "https://sampleflutter.herokuapp.com/";

Future<void> _startDownload(String savePath, String pdfname) async {
    print('startdownload :' + pdfname);

    Map<String, dynamic> result = {
      'isSuccess': false,
      'filePath': null,
      'error': null,
    };

    _fileUrl = _fileUrl + pdfname;
    
    print('url :' + _fileUrl);
    try {
      final response = await _dio.download(_fileUrl, savePath,
          onReceiveProgress: _onReceiveProgress);
      result['isSuccess'] = response.statusCode == 200;
      
    } catch (ex) {
      result['error'] = ex.toString();
    } finally {
      await _showNotification(result);
      pdfname = '';
      _fileUrl='';
    }
    pdfname = '';
    _fileUrl='';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileUrl = _fileUrl + pdfname;
```

because you concat every time _fileUrl with pdf name

```
Future<void> _startDownload(String savePath, String pdfname) async {
    print('startdownload :' + pdfname);

    Map<String, dynamic> result = {
      'isSuccess': false,
      'filePath': null,
      'error': null,
    };

    var fileUrl = _fileUrl + pdfname;
    
    print('url :' + fileUrl);
    try {
      final response = await _dio.download(fileUrl, savePath,
          onReceiveProgress: _onReceiveProgress);
      result['isSuccess'] = response.statusCode == 200;
      
    } catch (ex) {
      result['error'] = ex.toString();
    } finally {
      await _showNotification(result);
      pdfname = '';
      _fileUrl='';
    }
    pdfname = '';
    _fileUrl='';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine once but when I call it again with same or differen pdfname parameter , it adds it to the end of url.

Well, that's what you told it to do, isn't it?

```
_fileUrl = _fileUrl + pdfname;
```

Maybe you want to put your base URL in another variable, that you *do not* modify with every call, so you can build your URL independent of what the last URL was?